# delete all rows if a field contains a value from another record

Tags: sqlite

I've got a table like this:

```
Name        Code
-------------------
John        1235
John        1235/11
John        1236/12
Mary        2500
Mary        2500/8
Mary        3600
Mary        3600/9
```

I want to delete all the rows where the value of code is contained in another row.
In the example I want to delete these records:

```
Name        Code
-------------------
John        1235
Mary        2500
Mary        3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.value like t1.value || '/%'
                 );
```

If you don't want to actually delete the records, but just want a query to not return them:

```
select *
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.value like t1.value || '/%'
                 );
```

These assume that (as in the example), "is contained" really means "starts with before the "/".

Comment: In the actual table, it's not a "/" but an underscore "_". I tried to change it in your code but I was not able to make it works (I use SQLite). Sorry, this is the first epression I write in SQL, I'm googling to better understand it.

Comment: @Emmevvi . . . I don't undersrtand.  In the question it is clearly a slash.  But you should be able to use `like t1.value || '$_%' escape '$'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Delete From tablename t
Where Exists  
(Select * from table   
 Where charIndex(t.Code, Code) !=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I use SQLite, so I substitute charIndex with instr, but it doesn't work. What is "t"? I don't think it's the table name. Sorry I'm a very newbie.